# Is it possible for one app to check health of the other using any features of Spring framework?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring, spring-boot-starter

I have two instances of an app running. Is it possible for one app to check health of the other using any features of Spring framework ?

Comment: what do you mean two instances of the same app ? Can you elaborate a little more on that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can use Health Indicator with Actuator

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Available endpoints

> /health /info  /metrics /trace

it can return

```
{
    "status" : "UP"
}
```

and

```
{
    "status" : "DOWN",
    "myHealthCheck" : {
        "status" : "DOWN",
        "Error Code" : 1
     },
     "diskSpace" : {
         "status" : "UP",
         "free" : 209047318528,
         "threshold" : 10485760
     }
}
```

Read more here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on the answer by Hitham:

Let's say app A needs to report the status of App B. For that reason it seems that A depends on B for some service?

In any case, you can implement a `HealthIndicator` in A that attempts to call the service you need on B, using some benign, side-effect free operation.

Comment: He said 2 instances of the same App, you are stating them as two different apps

Comment: True. I guess he'd have to active those healtheck using a spring @Profile